# firefox saved session with private browsing

Tags: firefox

Yesterday I was using firefox with private browsing and i was read articles regarding installing ruby on rails. during that i found a nice article about how to install ruby on rails in windows. after working on that I wanted to save that page so i just choose "Save Session and Exit" a firefox add-one. after that when i opened firefox to check that page again it just opened in normal mode and there were no saved session. to make sure i started private browsing but didn't see saved session. Now I'm trying to find that ruby on rail page again on google but no success. can anyone please tell me if there is any way around to get that page from my cache/history or any other way. i searched on google for this issue but no success yet.

Comment: No you cannot, that's what **private** means.

Answer (score 4):

Nope. The whole point of private browsing is that no records are kept on your local machine.